# PHP - "1ebc0b7ef6141d11989f78748555751721187266c1dd4ece76fec267e5cb1aaf" == 1 is true

Tags: php

Why is the following PHP code block executed?

```
if ("1ebc0b7ef6141d11989f78748555751721187266c1dd4ece76fec267e5cb1aaf" == 1) {
    echo "WTF!";
}
```

This presumably means that `"1ebc0b7ef6141d11989f78748555751721187266c1dd4ece76fec267e5cb1aaf" == 1` is true?

For those stating that a string will always evaluate to true, why doesn't the following code block execute?

```
if ("111987266c1d" == 1) {
    echo "WTF, again!";
}
```

Comment: *"This presumably means that ... == 1 is true?"* - Yep.

Comment: hold on, let me make up a `wtf.php` test file ;-) brb. Edit: oh you deleted a comment I was responding to.

Comment: `("111987266c1d" != 1) == true`

Comment: It's trying to convert the string to an int, so since the first number is a 1, it matches to 1. If it was 2, it would return false.

Comment: `("111987266c1d" == 1) == false`, so why doesn't the first example evaluate to false also?

Comment: @aynber please see the second example, which doesn't evaluate to true. This also starts with a 1.

Comment: `var_dump((int)"1ebc0b7ef6141d11989f78748555751721187266c1dd4ece76fec267e5cb1aaf");` and `var_dump((int)"111987266c1d");` One of them `==` 1 and one of them doesn't.

Comment: The first character is `1` in `1ebc` followed by a letter, then you have `111...` had you placed a letter after the first 1, being `1a11` it would have evaluated to true; weirdest thing and there is an explanation for it; I'd just have to dig deeper as to why that is. Not my dv up there btw.

Comment: @Sinfieldd Just curious why you need to check that for though.

Comment: @Fred-ii- It's for an email verification system. If the token value stored in the DB is 1, then the email has been verified. Otherwise it should contain a random hash value which is part of the link sent to the user via email, the example was the first hash I had come across that provided an issue for me.

Comment: @Sinfieldd Oh I see. Well then; another way to have made sure if it was equal to that, would have been a `WHERE col_x = '1119...' AND email='xxx'` type of thing with a prepared statement though. Can't go wrong there, unless you're wanting to check it for with a GET array, then that may be a different story.

Comment: @Fred-ii- it's a GET array, but I'm using MongoDB and the query unserializes directly into objects, against which I am comparing the verification token property.

Comment: I'm not sure why I got down-voted for this question could someone explain?

Comment: @Sinfieldd Ok. Well, I'd have to test it out on my end but I don't foresee failure when using `$var = $_GET['x'];` with `?x=111987266c1d` and `WHERE col_x = '$var'`. That should evaluate to true. I say *"should"* yet am fairly confident on it. Maybe in having added more relevance to the question would have probably avoided downvotes and showing the GET array etc, to which I can honestly say was **not** mine.

Comment: @Sinfieldd further to my comment above; the dv reason could be vast. One possibility is that some may have thought it was unclear. I thought it was unclear also but I didn't vote in any way and felt the need to ask, which in turn came out to be something bigger than what was posted. The actual use of the sequence and its origin as well as its intended use, would have helped you out more here (IMHO), and could have also provided you with an alternate answer, one such as my own (in a way). What you posted doesn't seem to support the actual method of retrieval used; *just saying*.

Comment: @Sinfieldd Just so you know; I have a db setup for stuff like this when it comes to db/verification codes and my test was conclusive: being successful. I don't have MongoDB but I do have MySQL and given the `111987266c1d` string with a GET array, prepared statement and `num_rows` worked well, therefore I am unable to reproduce with what you provided for code. *Cheers*

Comment: Thanks Fred, you've been most helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When PHP compares a string to an int, it will convert the string to an int, which takes only the numbers at the beginning of the string, ending where the letters start.  I ran a few test examples through my tinker:

```
[1] > "1ebc0b7ef6141d11989f78748555751721187266c1dd4ece76fec267e5cb1aaf" == 1;
// true
[2] > "1ebc0b7ef6141d11989f78748555751721187266c1dd4ece76fec267e5cb1aaf" == '1';
// false
[3] > "1ebc0b7ef6141d11989f78748555751721187266c1dd4ece76fec267e5cb1aaf" == 2;
// false
[4] > "2ebc0b7ef6141d11989f78748555751721187266c1dd4ece76fec267e5cb1aaf" == 2;
// true
[5] > "2ebc0b7ef6141d11989f78748555751721187266c1dd4ece76fec267e5cb1aaf" == 3;
// false
[6] > "2ebc0b7ef6141d11989f78748555751721187266c1dd4ece76fec267e5cb1aaf" == 1;
// false
[7] > "10ebc0b7ef6141d11989f78748555751721187266c1dd4ece76fec267e5cb1aaf" == 1;
// false
[9] > "111987266c1d" == 1;
// false
```

This is further backed up by the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php):

> If you compare a number with a string or the comparison involves numerical strings, then each string is converted to a number and the comparison performed numerically.

Comment: That makes sense. So my second example isn't true because the number that starts is actually 111987266, and `(111987266 == 1) == false`. Thank you.

Comment: and that's the explanation I was going after ;-) right on the money